# Using Python (SciPy, NumPy) to analyse and compare two dependent data sets?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, analysis

I have two dependent sample populations of students in which data was obtained from them at two different times (in exam and out of exam). I would like to know the best way to compare these two dependent data sets to determine whether or not there is a correlation between the data that I have obtained in both situations.

An example would be that I have computed the efficiency in students completing a task in and out of exam conditions. I would like to be able to compare both samples and determine whether or not there is a correlation between the situation (in exam/not in exam) and efficiency. The data I have is as follows:

- Average efficiency in lab: 0.707788246655
- Standard Deviation: 0.262576910658
- Average efficiency out of lab: 0.722516939257
- Standard Deviation: 0.254893744412

I have a number of other metrics stored in .csv files which I would like to compare between samples such as speed, time taken etc. to determine if there is a correlation between these measures and the students situation.

I have determined that confidence intervals may be useful to see if there is a significant difference between samples, and I have also looked at the SciPy package for data analysis but I don't know where to start or what is and isn't useful.

Comment: This question seems to broad and not really on-topic for StackOverflow, rather, it sounds like a stats question. May try http://stats.stackexchange.com ? Honestly, it doesn't sound to me like you have the necessary background to formulate the question. You likely want some form of hypothesis test. Probably a paired t-test.

Comment: Are you trying to see if your exam has any influence on the different factors that you are trying to measure?

Isint that a standard t-test (or some variation)? From what you describe in the question, it looks like that.

Comment: @user202385 That's exactly what I'm trying to do. That's what I thought, but the data is not normally distributed so a t-test doesn't seem to be appropriate. Efficiency is heavily skewed towards high efficiency, for example.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I appreciate that I don't have the strongest background here which is why I'm asking. If this definitely isn't the appropriate place for the question, can I migrate it to the stats stack exchange or should I just re-ask the question over there?

Comment: I voted to move it, a moderator could do it immediately. My point was simply that if your question is really about figuring out a statistical *approach* then it belongs on CrossValidated. Once you have your answers about an approach, feel free to post any questions about *implementing the code* here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Perfect, thanks for your help.

Comment: For parametric tests it's not so much the standard deviation but the S.E.M. that will tell you whether a small difference in the means is significant. Since your data don't seem to be normally distibuted, the standard procedure in your case would be the Wilcoxon rank-sum test.

Comment: @PaulPanzer The data isn't paired. There are almost 3x more data points for the outside exam setting than there are for in exam.

Comment: The Wilcoxon rank-sum test is unpaired. You are probably thinking of the Wilcoxon signed rank test which is a different beast.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I was! The WR-S test is definitely going to be useful I think. Thanks!